# Given a single view, Django can only handle one request for that view at a time?

Tags: python, django

I was trying out some things with a new Django project (Django 1.8 and Python 2.7 32bit) and I encountered this situation.

This is my `view.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import time
def memory(request):
    print("Memory Request Started")
    yay = '123456'
    i = 0
    hi = []
    while i < 1000:
        i += 1
        if len(yay) > 1000000:
            hi.append(yay + str(i))
            if i%100 == 0:
               print(len(hi))
        else:
            yay += yay
    time.sleep(5)
    return HttpResponse(len(yay))


def memory2(request):
    print("Memory Request 2 Started")
    yay = '123456'
    i = 0
    hi = []
    while i < 1000:
        i += 1
        if len(yay) > 1000000:
            hi.append(yay + str(i))
            if i%100 == 0:
               print(len(hi))
        else:
            yay += yay
    time.sleep(5)
    return HttpResponse(len(yay))
```

As you can see `memory` and `memory2` are copies of each other.

My urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from view import memory, memory2

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'testdjango.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^test/', memory),
    url(r'^test2/', memory2),
)
```

Using this view and urls, I used `python manage.py runserver`. So I then used my browser and accessed `localhost:8000/test/` and `localhost:8000/test2/` at the same time. This crashed Django with a `MemoryError` (which was what I was trying to do).

However, when I used my browser and opened 2 pages of `localhost:8000/test/`, the requests ran sequentially and didn't crash Django. I tried Apache+mod_wsgi as well and encountered the same behavior. Is this expected Django behavior and if so why?

Comment: No. "Django" doesn't have any control over how many requests are made at one time; that's entirely the responsibility of the server.

Comment: But isn't django's development server multithreaded?

Comment: Yes. How are you determining that these are running sequentially?

Comment: The print statements print in sequential order (i.e. `Memory Request Started, 6144, 82, 182, 282, 382, 482, 582, 682, 682, 882, 982, Memory Request Started, 6144, 82, 182, 282, 382, 482, 582, 682, 682, 882, 982`). That and the fact that it isn't causing the `MemoryError` whereas running `memory` and `memory2` at the same time is.

Comment: Perhaps is just a no flush behavior.

Comment: @danihp What would be a way to check that?